# How do I explain to a woman that I don't want our babies ears pierced?

Tags: parents

If I where to ever have a child (big IF I know) there would be two issues that would be really important to me. I would like my children to be raised within the tenants of credo baptism and I would be desperately dissatisfied if a daughter of mine ears were pierced as a baby.

Whether the issue is abortion or baby ears getting pierced, the underlying bio-ethical considerations are the same. A person has sole rights over his or her own body. Sometimes babies get sick and decision over there bodies have to be made for there best interest but a parent should not choose this for a baby.

Now in the days when I used to teach there was this one girl who had a tiny diamond stud earing. When I taught her music theory she used to look down at her books while she did her exercises and the diamond would sparkle in the summer sunshine. It was striking to this bachelor how pretty that was.

If I were to have a daughter it would be nice if she had such a tasteful ear ring but she would have to be at least 6 years old and under no circumstances would I allow her to be coerced into doing it.

So, in closing we actually come to crux of this question. How do you as man explain this issue to a woman when you are exploring your beliefs in regards to parenting without it sounding petty or childish. It may just be a small thing, but it is important to me.

Comment: This probably isn't a good question for this site as it stands, but it's a very good question for when you are starting a relationship with someone with whom you may wish to have children.  Really, just say it like you did to us.  Then listen.  There's 0 chance that you and  your partner will have identical views on all things childraising, but there's a good chance that two people acting in good faith can understand what compromises will be required and decide whether or not those compromises are acceptable to both.

Comment: This isn't a parenting question, but rather an interpersonal one, between you and the potential mother of your son/daughter(s). Maybe better on Interpersonal Skills?

Comment: Not suitable on Interpersonal Skills.SE